# Azure release pipeline error 409 when Publish to Xamarin forms windows Package Flight

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, xamarin.uwp

I am running pipelines for Android, iOS and UWP build but in case of UWP the release pipeline is failing.
I am running Azure release pipeline for Xamarin forms windows Package Flight but it is failing with the error 409 with a message

“[error]Status 409: {“code”:“InvalidState”,“message”:“Unable to create a new submission, while pending submission 1152921505693654453 has not yet been committed”} CorrelationId: id”.

I have asked this question on the Developer community portal https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-release-pipeline-error-409-when-Pu/1556591Developer.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?